# using custom QMetaType with QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to load and store a custom QMetaType using QDataStream object. Here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString test1("/test1/");
    const QString path1(QDir::homePath()+test1);
    qDebug() << "path1 variable is " << path1;
    QDir apphome(path1);
    qDebug() << "apphome path is " << apphome.absolutePath();
    if (!apphome.mkdir(path1)) { qDebug() << "mkdir returned false. directory already exists?"; }
    if(!apphome.setCurrent(path1)) { qDebug() << "did not set current directory"; }
    qDebug() << "apphome path is " << apphome.absolutePath();
    Basic basic1;
    Basic basic2;
    basic1.value = 14;
    QFile file1("file1name");
    if (!file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) { qDebug() << "file1 not open."; }
    QDataStream dataStream1(&file1);
    QVariant qvar1;
    qvar1.setValue(basic1);
    dataStream1 << (quint32)12345;
    dataStream1 << qvar1;
    file1.close();
    file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream dataStream2(&file1);
    quint32 magic;
    QVariant qvar2;
    dataStream1 >> magic;
    qDebug() << "magic number is " << magic;
    dataStream2 >> qvar2;
    file1.close();
    basic2 = qvar2.value<Basic>();
    qDebug() << "14 = " << basic1.value << " = " << basic2.value << ".";

    //MainWindow w;
    //w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The magic number comes back, but there is a message  `QVariant::save: unable to save type 'Basic' (type id: 1026).` and then of course `QVariant::load: unable to load type 1026.` and then `14 = 14 = 0`. The Basic class is just from the QMetaType documentation:

```
struct Basic
{
    Basic();
    Basic(const Basic &basic);
    ~Basic();
    int value;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Basic)

// basic.cpp

#include "basic.h"

Basic::Basic() {}

Basic::Basic(const Basic &basic)
{
    value = basic.value;
}

Basic::~Basic(){}
```

I'm running out of ideas, does anyone know what is causing the problem? The version of Qt is 5.10.1.

Comment: you didn't implement streaming. also a dublicate

Comment: Is that really the problem? I thought that was taken care of automatically. It's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: for some built-in supported types, yes, `QVariant`does it (implemented directly), otherwise it either calls that operator or prints those messages. This is not LUA or java, so serialization isn't automated on level of object representation. There is `QSetting` related question that boils down to the same problem.

Comment: Correction: it *is mentioned in the documentation, but only (if I'm not mistaken) under the descriptions for qRegisterMetaType and qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because compiler can't read your mind, you need describe how serialization is possible, e.g.

```
struct Basic
{
    Basic();
    Basic(const Basic &basic);
    ~Basic();
    int value;

    friend QDataStream & operator << (QDataStream &arch, const Basic& object)
    {
        arch << object.value;
        return arch;
    }

    friend QDataStream & operator >> (QDataStream &arch, Basic& object)
    {
        arch >> object.value;
        return arch;
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Basic);
```

in main()

```
qRegisterMetaType<Basic>("Basic");
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Basic>("Basic");
```

before save\load operation would happen. Q_DECLARE_METATYPE is required to store type with QVariant, those two are required to register object's "big three"  to manage it as resource and its serialization methods. Output:

```
path1 variable is  "C:/Users/Yaroslav/test1/"
apphome path is  "C:/Users/Yaroslav/test1"
mkdir returned false. directory already exists?
apphome path is  "C:/Users/Yaroslav/test1"
magic number is  12345
14 =  14  =  14 .
```

P.S. Note, if you left `return a.exec();` with no window present, you get program staying in memory forever until you stop it.

Comment: @LuciusSchoenbaum waait.. you're doing ithat way.. you forgot  one line. you forgot to register it

Comment: I registered it and now it is working! Thank you. :)